# Releasing an app - Developed on one account, releasing/approving on another

Tags: iphone

We have developed an application for a company who want to release it under their own account. It has been developed on our account and has had provisioning profiles attached to it from our own account. What is the best way to do this? Do I have to send them the xCode project and talk them through how to attack a provisioning profile to the project? Or can I just get their login details and create a provisioning profile from the Mac in the office and do it for them? Or is there a "transfer to different account" option?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your last question: Apps cannot be easily transferred to another account (when already available at the App Store).

But both of the other suggestions would work: An app is not tied to an account until you submit it via iTunesConnect. So you can just use provisioning profiles from another account to build the app for submission. Of course, you can do that in your office, using the credentials of the customer, or you can just hand over the project and let the customer do the submission.